# avoid repetitive code Java

Tags: java, refactoring

I am working on ETL Java project and it does 3 things
extract - read the data from a table
transform the data to JSON 
Load the data
It works fine. The issue is I am doing it for each table. The way I have right now is

```
   class ETLHelper
   {
     private Person read(ResultSet results){
       Person p = new Person();
       p.setPersonId(results.getString("PERSON_ID"));
       p.setPersonName(results.getString("PERSON_NAME"));
       return p;
     }
     private String transform(Person p){
       TransformPerson t = new TransformPerson();
       t.setTransformPersonId(p.getPersonId);
       t.setTransformPersonName(p.getPersonName);
       PersonEData eData = new PersonEData();
       eData.setDate1(p.date1);
       eData.setDate2(p.date2);
       t.seteData(eData);
       PersonDetails pd = new PersonDetails();
       pd.settransformdata(t);
       return writeValueAsString(pd);
     }
     public void etl(){
       Connection c = null;
       PreparedStatement p = null;
       ResultSet r = null;

       c = getConnection();
       p = c.prepareStatement(getSql());
       r = p.executeQuery();

       while(r.next()){
        messages.add(transform(read(r)));
       /*code for loading data*/
       }
     }

   }
```

Person.Java:

```
 @JsonTypeName(value = "PERSON")
 @JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
  public class Person{
   @JsonProperty(value = "PERSON_ID")
   private String personId;
   //getter and setter for personId
   @JsonProperty(value = "PERSON_NAME")
   private String personName;
   //getter and setter for personName
}
```

TransformPerson.java:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "Person")
class TransformPerson{
 private String transformPersonName;
 private String transformPersonId;  
 /*getter and setter for transformPersonName and tranformPersonId*/
 @override
 String toString(){
  return "Person [name =" + transformPersonName + ", id = " + transformPeronId "]";
  }
 }
```

PersonEdata:

```
private String date1;
private String date2;
/*getter and setter*/
@override
public String toString(){
 return "PersonEdata [date1=" + date1 +", date2=" + date2 + "]";
}
```

So a Person class, a class needed for transformation and etl class is written for each table. There are also some additional classes like PersonEdata that returns JSON when toString() is called. Is there anyway can I change this design to avoid writing the similar code for each table? There are some constraints. Each table is different and they transformation class is needed because there are other programs that uses the JSON generated so we need to generate JSON that needs to understood by those programs.

Comment: Why are there 3 variations of `Person`?  Why not have `read()` directly create a `PersonDetail` and set it's values, and get rid of `Person` and `TransformPerson`?

Comment: I have to think it through.. earlier when I started this project I thought it will be cleaner to have Person that corresponds to table and transform person data to the way the other programs needed. So what you are saying is move all the code in Person and Transform into PersonDetail?

Comment: What do you mean by _all the code_?  The posted code looks like simple java beans.

Answer (score 0):

In your current solution, you have created :

1. Person class - to hold the data retrieved from DB
2. PersonTransform class - to copy the data from Person to other representation and have extended the capability to create JSON by overrinding `toString()`

To keep it simple what you can do is:

1. Have single Class like Person for each entity (Table) - which is JSON Serializable.
2. Don't override the `toString` method to represent the JSON representation - use JSON serializer instead.

Comment: I feel I did not do a good job in original question. I need Json in specific format like Edata +"Transform" + RootName(Person) + Person details. For example 

    {"date1":"01012018","date2":"01012018","transform":{"Person":{person details}}}

If I have all data (edata and person data and there are some more classes as well), how would I use one Java object to serialize to multiple Json arrays. It is going to be one Json object but few fields will be part of one array then other fields (from another class) needs to be appended. I am not sure how to do do it.